# Multiple Paragraphs with \parshape

Tags: paragraphs, parshape

When using a `\parshape`, I can use

```
\newline\hspace*{0.5\parindent}
```

to produce a new "paragraph" and still continue with the current `\parshape`.

Is it possible to leave a blank line and still get the effect of the above? That is, the blank line should *not* become a `\par` as that resets the `\parshape`.

The MWE below (with the `\par` commented out and the `\newline\hspace*{0.5\parindent}` uncommented) produces the desired output:

[image]

but I would like to be able to leave a blank line and when using a `\parshape`, automatically use some macro that yields the desired behavior.

### Note:

- This is used for a few paragraphs which fit on one page.
- Besides visually being easier to read/edit, having a blank line also allows for regular typesetting as well. I need to be able to typeset the content in this environment normally as well.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newcommand*{\Text}{%
\sloppy\noindent
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. 
\par% <-- would prefer this though, or even better a blank line
%\newline\hspace*{0.5\parindent}% <-- Replacing the \par with this works
Curabitur dictum
gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. 
Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. 
Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices.%
}%


\newcommand*{\TitleParShape}{%
    0.40\hsize 0.20\hsize
}%
\newcommand*{\BodyParShape}{%
    0.35\hsize 0.30\hsize
    0.30\hsize 0.40\hsize
    0.25\hsize 0.50\hsize
    0.20\hsize 0.60\hsize
    0.15\hsize 0.70\hsize
    0.10\hsize 0.80\hsize
    0.05\hsize 0.90\hsize
    0.00\hsize 1.00\hsize
}%

\newcommand*{\MyParShape}{%
    \parshape 9
    \TitleParShape
    \BodyParShape
}%

\begin{document}
\parshape 1
\TitleParShape
{\bfseries\centering My Title\par\smallskip}%
\parshape 8
\BodyParShape
\Text
\end{document}
```

Comment: what is the purpose of the `\hspace*{0.5\parindent}`? it applies only to one text line?

Comment: @jfbu I guess it is to highlight the new paragraph (without the line skipped like in your answer), but the guess part is important, I'm not certain.

Comment: @jfbu: It was intended to fake a new paragraph.

Answer (score 3):

## Rewrite working in more cases

I've removed the original answer and added this rewrite. The rewrite should work with more par shapes (the original answer only worked for par shapes with up to 8 definitions).

How it works:

I'm redefining the `\par` macro to insert some code (so use with caution, if in doubt group it, the redefinition is made local).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newcommand*{\Text}{%
\sloppy\noindent
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. 

Curabitur dictum
gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. 
Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. 
Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices.%
}%


\makeatletter

\@ifdefinable\peterCountA{\newcount\peterCountA}% stores lines already done
\@ifdefinable\peterCountB{\newcount\peterCountB}% stores prevgraf
\@ifdefinable\peterCountC{\newcount\peterCountC}% stores BodyParShape number

\newcommand*{\TitleParShape}{%
    0.40\hsize 0.20\hsize
}%

\peterCountC=8 % number of items in the BodyParShape
\newcommand*{\BodyParShape}{%
    0.35\hsize 0.30\hsize
    0.30\hsize 0.40\hsize
    0.25\hsize 0.50\hsize
    0.20\hsize 0.60\hsize
    0.15\hsize 0.70\hsize
    0.10\hsize 0.80\hsize
    0.05\hsize 0.90\hsize
    0.00\hsize 1.00\hsize
}

\@ifdefinable\eatParShapeLine
  {\long\def\eatParShapeLine#1\hsize #2\hsize {}}
\@ifdefinable\myif@fiAa % equivalent to \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  {\long\def\myif@fiAa#1\fi#2#3{\fi#2}}
\@ifdefinable\myif@fiBb % equivalent to \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  {\long\def\myif@fiBb\fi#1#2{\fi#2}}

% helper macro to expand the first token in the last argument once
\newcommand\myexp@NnV[3]
  {%
    \expandafter\myexp@NnV@\expandafter{#3}{#1}{#2}%
  }
\newcommand\myexp@NnV@[3]
  {%
    #2{#3}{#1}%
  }
% a wrapper around \eatParShapeLine to eat the first #1 lines in the parshape #2
\newcommand\eatParShapeLines[2]
  {%
    \myexp@NnV\eatParShapeLinesAux{#1}{#2}%
  }
% expandable loop
\newcommand\eatParShapeLinesAux[2]
  {%
    % if still loops to do
    \ifnum#1>0
      % reinsert the first token/group after \fi
      \myif@fiAa
    \else
      % reinsert the second token/group after \fi
      \myif@fiBb
    \fi
    {%
      % reinsert the \eatParShapeLinesAux with #1 decreased by 1 and the first
      % two \hsize fractions from #2 eaten
      \expandafter\myexp@NnV\expandafter\eatParShapeLinesAux\expandafter
        {\the\numexpr#1-1}{\eatParShapeLine#2}%
    }
    % loop is done, reinsert the shortened parshape
    {#2}%
  }
\newcommand\BodyParShapeNum[2]
  {%
    % \parshape expands its arguments to find numbers and dimensions
    \parshape #1 \eatParShapeLines{#2}\BodyParShape
  }

\newcommand*{\MyParShape}{%
    \parshape 9
    \TitleParShape
    \BodyParShape
}%

\newcommand\ParshapeMultiPar
  {%
    % setup initial BodyParShape
    \parshape \peterCountC \BodyParShape
    % no lines processed yet
    \peterCountA=0
    % redefine \par to reinsert the left over parshape entries
    \def\par
      {%
        % end the previous paragraph
        \endgraf
        % save the \prevgraf counter (lines of last paragraph)
        \peterCountB\prevgraf
        % check whether there are still lines left from BodyParShape
        \ifnum\numexpr\peterCountC-\peterCountA>\peterCountB
          % update lines already done
          \advance\peterCountA\peterCountB
          % set the parshape for the next par, leave out first \peterCountA
          % lines
          \expandafter\BodyParShapeNum\expandafter
            {\the\numexpr\peterCountC-\peterCountA}{\peterCountA}%
          % fake a parindent
          \noindent\hspace*{.5\parindent}
        \else
          % else is executed if the BodyParShape was ended in the previous
          % paragraph. In this case revert the redefinition of \par
          \let\par\endgraf
        \fi
      }%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\parshape 1
\TitleParShape
{\bfseries\centering My Title\par\smallskip}%
\parshape 8
\BodyParShape
\Text

\ParshapeMultiPar
\Text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This seems to work well, even without the `duckuments` package. :-)  Can you add a brief explanation as to how it works as it is not obvious by looking at the code?

Comment: I added the `duckuments` package sometime during testing and didn't remove it, sorry. I'll add a slight rewrite soonish.

Comment: @PeterGrill I rewrote the code. The first version had its limitations (max. 8 parshape entries). Also the code is now commented, I hope the comments are enough explanation, if something's left, feel free to ask.

Comment: @PeterGrill just found out that the code might bug if your `\Text` is in a group but the `\ParshapeMultiPar` isn't (so `\ParshapeMultiPar\begingroup\Text\endgroup` is no good idea).

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this what you want. I added a blank line in output via a `\parskip` setting. I removed from `\Text` all formatting as you say you want to use macro elsewhere. The `\resumebody` by default does nothing, but it can be used to resume some parshape. (not much needs to be known on the parshape, perhaps the number of lines it deals with; I did not add error checking if previous paragraph already exhausted the parshape.).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newcommand*{\Text}{%
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing
  elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae,
  felis.

  \resumebody
  Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget,
  consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque.
  Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada
  fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus
  sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices.%
}%


\newcommand*{\TitleParShape}{%
    0.40\hsize 0.20\hsize
}%
\newcommand*{\BodyParShape}{%
    0.35\hsize 0.30\hsize % 10 tokens per line spec
    0.30\hsize 0.40\hsize
    0.25\hsize 0.50\hsize
    0.20\hsize 0.60\hsize
    0.15\hsize 0.70\hsize
    0.10\hsize 0.80\hsize
    0.05\hsize 0.90\hsize
    0.00\hsize 1.00\hsize
}%

\newcommand*{\MyParShape}{%
    \parshape 9
    \TitleParShape
    \BodyParShape
}%

\usepackage{xinttools}

\newcommand*{\resumebodyparshape}{%
   \parshape \numexpr8-\prevgraf-1\relax
   \xintTrim{10*\prevgraf+10}{\BodyParShape}%
}

\newcommand*{\resumebody}{}

\begin{document}
\parshape 1
\TitleParShape
{\bfseries\centering My Title\par\smallskip}%
\parshape 8
\BodyParShape
\let\resumebody\resumebodyparshape
\edef\currentparfillskip{\the\parfillskip}\parfillskip0pt
\edef\currentparskip{\the\parskip}\parskip\baselineskip
  \sloppy
  \noindent 
  \Text
\parfillskip\currentparfillskip
\par
\parskip\currentparskip
\let\resumebody\empty
\end{document}
```

I used `xinttools` per convenience, even more light-weight package `xintkernel` is enough via its `\xintgobble` macro. (but then I need to do add a bit of `\expandafter` for expanding `\BodyParShape` before gobbling, i.e. this works:

```
\usepackage{xintkernel}

\newcommand*{\resumebodyparshape}{%
   \edef\temp{%
   \parshape \numexpr8-\prevgraf-1\relax
   \noexpand\romannumeral\noexpand\xintgobble{10*\prevgraf+10}\BodyParShape}%
   \temp
}
```

or this

```
\usepackage{xintkernel}

\newcommand*{\resumebodyparshape}{%
   \parshape \numexpr8-\prevgraf-1\relax
   \expandafter\resumebodyaux\expandafter{\BodyParShape}%
}%

\def\resumebodyaux#1{\romannumeral\xintgobble{10*\prevgraf+10}#1}
```

and needs only `xintkernel` package.)

[image]

Comment: I am removing from `\BodyParShape` one more line than the previous paragraphs had. Perhaps this "one more" is not what @PeterGrill asked. But it felt more coherent this way.

Comment: The LaTeX `\list` code uses the fact that `{\par}` (or rather `{\@@par}` for them) does not kill the parshape. But it starts over from the first line spec, it does not continue where it stopped. Try it by ending first par with `{%`, leaving blank line and then a line with `}%` and continuing on next line.

Comment: I am assuming the 8 is the number of lines in the `\parshape`, but what is the 10? Also, don't think this will work if there is more than one paragraph.

Comment: Yes this will not work as is for more than more preceding paragraph. The 10 is the number of tokens in `0.xy\hsize 0.rs\hsize`. The `-1` (or `+10`) is because I deliberately skip one of the parshape line to correspond to empty line in output (obtained via `\parskip`).

Comment: (I fiddled with `\parfillskip` quite deliberately to force the first paragraph last line to use the full width as allowed by the parshape, I see from other answers that this may not be the expectation, but I felt it was better in accord with interrupting and resuming a parshape)

Comment: @PeterGrill: it is possible to recover the number of entries of the parshape dynamically, the "8" does not have to be hard-coded. Besides it can be tested if parshape has been exhausted, thus avoiding an error next. What kind of mark-up do you allow in `\Text`?

Comment: I would prefer to minimize the additional markup in the actual text. I have stored in a macro exactly how many lines  there are in total (not per paragraph) and can pass that to any other macro _outside_ of the actual `\Text`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're brave there is `l3galley`… I think there are too many issues with `l3galley` to really use it yet, but it shows what might be possible in the future.

**Some notes:**

- I've used internal variables to stop the cutout at the end of the environment (in case of short paragraphs). This seems like a bad idea, but I can't make the cutouts stop any other way.
- `l3galley` breaks stuff.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{l3galley}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \l__grill_indents_clist
\clist_set:Nn \l__grill_indents_clist
{
  0.35\hsize, 0.30\hsize, 0.25\hsize, 0.20\hsize,
  0.15\hsize, 0.10\hsize, 0.05\hsize, 0.00\hsize
}
\NewDocumentEnvironment { pyramid } { }
{
  \dim_set:Nn \l_galley_par_indent_dim { 0pt }
  \use:x
  {
    \exp_not:N \galley_cutout_left:nn { 0 }
    {
      \clist_use:Nn \l__grill_indents_clist { , }
    }
  }
  \use:x
  {
    \exp_not:N \galley_cutout_right:nn { 0 }
    {
      \clist_use:Nn \l__grill_indents_clist { , }
    }
  }
  \sloppy
}
{
  \galley_par:
  \seq_gclear:N \g__galley_cutout_left_seq
  \seq_gclear:N \g__galley_cutout_right_seq
  \bool_gset_false:N \g__galley_cutout_active_bool
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\begin{pyramid}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
  vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.

  Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer
  id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant
  morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
  Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum
  urna fringilla ultrices.
\end{pyramid}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Is `l3galley` considered experimental? Don't see that mentioned in the documentation. Also, are the cases where `l3galley` is known to break things listed somewhere?

Comment: @PeterGrill, yes. It is in the [`l3experimental` bundle](https://ctan.org/pkg/l3experimental). I don't know of a list of things that break, but there are the relevant [issues on GitHub](https://github.com/latex3/latex3/labels/xgalley).

Comment: The `l3experimental bundle` link mentions `xgalley`, not `l3galley`. Are they perhaps the same? Not sure why the experimental note can not be in each of the packages as well?

Comment: @PeterGrill, `xgalley` contains some higher level templates built on top of `l3galley`. Both are part of the experimental LaTeX 3 packages.